# IIS Wordpress Reverse Proxy New Post Timeout

Tags: wordpress, iis, https, timeout, reverse-proxy

We finally managed to install Wordpress on IIS with a reverse proxy on Netscaler. The site works fine except when I attempt to make a new post.

I click on Publish, after some time I get a timeout with error net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

The URL is as per below, which also seems somewhat wrong since we are coming from https.
http://domain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=2011&action=edit&message=6&doing_wp_cron=1417706600.9032890796661376953125

When I click back into the Posts page, I see that the post has been created. Also, clicking back shortly after I clicked on Publish, Postr has been created. This also occurs when deleting more than one post, deleting only one works though.

When I post using the browser on the web server the post is published, I get the refreshed page with message 'Post Published'.

Any suggestions? Many thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I found the problem.. . I really hope this helps someone else, as usual it was relatively simple and the answer was in my last edit which shows doing_wp_cron.

Commenting out the line below, new posts now posts as they should:

```
define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Time for a beer!